# Popup hover in Open layers Framed Cloud

Tags: dictionary, gis

Ive googled about this and i dunno if im just searching using a wrong keyword.

Here's the scenario.

I'm auto generating a lot of markers in my map. Everytime I hover over any marker, a popup displays. When I hover out, the popup toggles off. But the thing is, when I zoom out my map, the  markers get crowded in one area. Since that is the case, when I hover over any marker, the popup that displays does not toggle now. Hence, it remains popped in my map until there are a lot of popups displayed in my map.

Any idea why is this happening?

Thanks for any inputs guys.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't experienced this before. I would suggest bug in your code, rather than OpenLayers misbehaviour. Something like

```
selectControl.events.on({
    featurehighlighted: function() {/* show popup */},
    featureunhighlighted: function() {/* hide popup */}
});
```

should work correctly, even if there is lot of features on the map.